# Class name before variable in PHP function argument

Tags: php, oop

In lots of PHP scripts I see things such as this:

```
public function __construct(Container $ci) {

}
```

I understand what a constructor does and how to pass a variable. However I'm not sure what `Container` means in this example? Is this the equivalent of `$ci = new Container;` ?

Comment: [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)

Comment: @Faraz There is no PHP 6. Only PHP 5 and 7.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois my bad php 7. current documentation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is just [**type hinting**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) the method's `$ci` parameter, meaning that you should pass an argument declared as an instance of `Container` like so:

```
$cont = new Container();

$obj = new YourClass($cont);
```

Comment: Not should but have to.

Comment: If you do not pass a Container object to the constructor, it will ,throw a fatal error(Uncaught TypeError) and abort. See https://myprogrammingnotes.com/class-name-function-arguments.html

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for "Type Hinting" and using the broken links above, in PHP this is now known as Type Declaration.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).